# MySQL server has gone away during large file import

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

After 8h import large file, I've receive an error:

```
Fatal error: Query failed. MySQL server has gone away in /home/strefa/public_html/impo/sql/MySqlDb.php on line 72
```

I know, it is popular problem and they are many solutions how to fix it.
But I checked almost all and changed in  /etc/mysql/my.cnf

wait_timeout = 999999
max_allowed_packet = 800MB

But nothing helps, error still exist.

Comment: Is it a remote server? May have been a network error out of your control (a link went down, router or switch got rebooted, etc) - it's not uncommon for this sort of thing to happen during an 8-hour operation. It's also possible that the MySQL service was restarted for some reason. Can you split the import into smaller pieces?

Comment: Yes it is. I wouldn't say that is network problem. The time when error appears is always same